# What is the proper formatting of the Subject Tag in XMP?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, xmp

My intention is to assign tags to each image based on the content in the image.For example

[image]

This image can be be assigned tags ***Tulips,Flower etc***

So can i assign `subject` like `tulips,flower` and so on separated by commas.Will the major software's and websites recognize these tags properly.

Comment: "Will major software and websites recognize tags in XMP Subject?" is a very different question from "What is the proper formatting of the XMP Subject tag?". Which do you mean?

Comment: @mattdm I mean in such scenarios whats the way to assign the tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interface for a lot of programs with regards to keywords is to show them as a comma separated string.  But the important thing to remember is that they are not stored as such.  They are stored as individual, separate items, as in @Romeo Ninov XMP example.

To do this in exiftool, you command would be
`exiftool -Subject=Tulips -Subject=Flower FILE`
Note that this will overwrite any previously existing keywords.

If you wanted to **add** new keywords without overwriting previous ones, you would add a + sign before the equal
`exiftool -Subject+=Tulips -Subject+=Flower FILE`

If you write it as your comma separated list, like this:
`exiftool -Subject="Tulips,Flower" FILE`
then you are writing a **single** keyword with the value of "Tulips,Flower".

If you find it easier to write it as a comma separated list, then you can add the [-sep option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#sep-STR--separator).  But you must be careful of stray spaces.  For example, using `-sep ","` if you try to write "Tulips,Flower, Yellow" (note space after the comma before Yellow) then you are writing a keyword of (space)Yellow, not Yellow.

Read [exiftool FAQ #17](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q17) carefully for details about list type tags.

Comment: This works fine,but does not work when image already has tags.

Comment: Which part does not work?  As I mentioned, if it already has tags, then you need to use the `+=` format.  Make sure and read the exiftool FAQ 17 completely.  It's all covered there.  If you have specific examples, you can head over to the [exiftool forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/) and get lots of help there.

Comment: Please see my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619438/overwriting-existing-tags-using-exiftool

Comment: Will doing the += add new tags if there are no tags ?

Comment: `+=` will add new *list* type tags even if there were none to start with.  For simple string tags tags, you will get an error using `+=` as that is an incorrect usage. Using just the equal sign `=` will overwrite any previous tags. I cannot comment on your other post as no knowledge of C# or .net.  All I can suggest is test directly on the command line, then try to reproduce the same command in your other code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I will get back with some samples after testing.

Comment: I'd suggest posting on the exiftool forum (link above).  More experts to help with the problem there.

Comment: okay... Thanks..........

Comment: Had one more question.Is this subject tag compatible with the `keyword` tag used in lightroom?

Comment: Yes, `Subject` is where keywords are stored and are part of the IPTC-Core (see [IPTC Keywords](https://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata#keywords)).  `Keywords` is part of the older IPTC IIM standard.  Lightroom will read from both and I think would combine the two if there were any differences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how Lightroom write in `XMP` keywords for file:

```
  <lr:hierarchicalSubject>
    <rdf:Bag>
     <rdf:li>Edfu</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>Egypt</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>ancient</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>archeology</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>architecture</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>building</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>history</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>museum</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>religion</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>temple</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>tourism</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>travel</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
   </lr:hierarchicalSubject>
```

And this is accepted in all major stock agencies (Adobe, GettyImages, Shutterstock) as well as photo sharing or/and selling sites like 500px, Flickr

The command you can use to incorporate this info in image is something like:

```
exiftool "-xmp<=xmp.xml" image_file
```

Comment: thanks for the info.In this case what's the proper way to use exiftool to write this data?

Comment: I edit my answer, adding command line about @techno

Comment: thanks.. but isnt it possible to do this without creating a separate 'xml' file? Just via command line.

Comment: @techno, for sure there is a way. But I do not know how :)

Comment: Thanks :) ... but your command is producing the following error https://imgur.com/a/pzwnIep

Comment: @techno, the example in my answer is only part of `XMP` file. You should use complete one with this part incorporated.

Comment: ahm... i see........